# Dropdown menu flashes and disappeared on mobile only

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a sub-menu inside the navbar under the Services nav-item.

The **expected** behavior is once the Service is clicked, the sub-menu shows up. The actual **behavior** is: once the Service is clicked, the sub-menu flashes and disappears.

```
  <nav id="main-menu">
                    <ul class="sf-navbar">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#home">
                                <div data-i18n="nav.home">Home</div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <div data-i18n="nav.services.title">Title</div>
                            </a>

                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#service">
                                        <div data-i18n="nav.services.ourservices">Our Services</div>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#how">
                                        <div data-i18n="nav.services.howwework">How We Work</div>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#areascontainer">
                                        <div data-i18n="servicearea.title">Service Area</div>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#why">
                                        <div data-i18n="why.title">Why Choose Us</div>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
.....
</nav>
```

JS code:

```
wei.header = {

        init: function(){

            wei.header.superfish();

        },             

        superfish: function() {

            $( main_menu ).superfish({

                popUpSelector   : 'ul',
                delay   : 250,
                speed   : 350
            });

        },
```

...

I have tried to debug it, but have no clue where to start.

Here is the code that I am working on.
http://weistudio.com.au/

Comment: why down vote? happy to learn.

Comment: Not the downvoter, but maybe because of the link? Not sure.

Comment: thanks @jhpratt I forgot to explain the url, it's where the code is, I put it there just for viewing all the code.

Comment: I have several questions. 
1. You writing that expected behavior is to show submenu with click. Should it work without js? As now it showed on hover.
2. Probably the issue you describing is because of `#`, which should be canceled with something like `event.preventDefault()` on click.
3. I can't reproduce the issue in Chrome, as nothing flashes and works well, except of menu working with hover, not with a click.

Comment: Hi @extempl thanks for your reply. I have to say sorry, that the issue only happens on MOBILE. To answer your question, 1. I use SuperFish.js(sf) so I guess the sf should have the js; 3. You can reproduce it only on mobile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, SuperFish fails here on `touchEnd` event and only for the menu shown when you at the very top of the page (it works if you scroll page a bit - there is a clone of this menu).

To prevent it you could use something like `<a href="#" onTouchEnd="(function (e) {e.preventDefault()})(event)">`.
Or move it to an external method and use like this (as you using jQuery already):

`$('.header-container').on('touchend', '.sf-with-ul', function (e) {e.preventDefault()})`

Comment: you are the saver~! thanks a lot man! How did you figure it out? I sat here for hours and had no clue where to start my debugging. Can you please pass on the way how you find the clue? Appreciated~!

Comment: @Franva
I used chrome dev tools to simulate mobile device - this helps to debug with access to the current state of the code. As the lib works with clicks on mobile I realized that there is something with handling `click` event. When trying to press-and-hold I realized, that menu opens on `touchstart`, so there is something wrong with `touchend` event handling. 
Actually, this is mostly like a hotfix, not a real solution, as the root of the problem is that SF hides menu on touchend within some timeout (probably related to config's delay) or something like that. The submenu works as intended

Comment: thanks. now I know how you figured out the issue :) the SF seems stopped updating its code. Thanks again